# Make global function in webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm making a typescript plugin with webpack. Everything works well but I have a problem with making it visible from outside. For example, I have files:

```
/* ./src/a.ts */
class A {
    constructor(args) {...}
}
export default A;

/* ./src/app.ts */
import A from "./a.ts";
function init(args) {
   new A(args);
}
export { init };

/* ./index.html */
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
...

<!-- webpack bundle ts files into ./dist/app.js -->
<script src="./dist/app.js"></script>
<script>init({...});</script>

</body>
</html>
```

With this I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined`. In bundled file I can see that this function is not global, but inside other function like this:

```
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) { ... }
```

How to make this function public?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Exporting from module does not make an entity global. You can either directly add it as a member to window:

```
window.init = init;
```

or, better still, move the init invocation to a typescript module - which in this case should be your webpack entry point.

Comment: is this really the only solution to make the the functions of a module visible outside  itself if I am going to bundle them with webpack? I am working on a large project and can't possibly go and change this by adding `windows.functionname = functionname;` for each one. Is there a better solution for a case like mine?

Comment: Is it not feasible for you to make everything consumed through webpack ? Basically bundle whatever is consuming this variable.

Comment: I do bundle together the file that defines this variable and the files that use it, all of them. But the function definition still remains invisible to the function implementation. Because, again, each file (and not the final bundle) is enclosed into its function wrapper (e.g. a webpack bundle looks like `function(N,a){the code of javascript file here}function(N){the code of another javascript file here}`). am I missing something?

Comment: If you are bundling everything you should be exporting the function from the source file and importing it in the file that uses it.