# Unable to call functions in minified js files from the html page

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify, uglifyjs

I have onclick functions that are called from the html file and post compression of the javascript files, the functions are no longer visible to the html page even though the function names are unchanged.

I've tried to use UglifyJsPlugin with diferent configurations like below but the html page cannot find the functions :

```
 new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
            warnings: false,
            parse: {},
            compress: false,
            mangle: false, 
            output: null,
            toplevel: false,
            nameCache: null,
            ie8: false,
            keep_fnames: true,
            sourcemap: !isProd
        }
```

What's the solution for this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't use those `on...` attributes in the html file because of this reason. You should use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: And your `onclick` functions worked, when you used webpack without uglifyjs? Because the problem should already exists due to the webpack bundling process even without uglify.

Comment: @t.niese, You rigth about addEventListener, but replace around 500 on... events looks crazy. And it doesn't work with native webpack compression

Comment: Well either use uglifyjs without webpack and keep the function names, or use webpack with uglify and full compression and explicitly export the functions to the global namespace: [Make global function in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797042)

Comment: @t.niese, Im noob xD and I don't understand the idea with global function =( Can you explain me it more detail or provide a little fiddle example?

Comment: There is not much to say about it. As mentioned in the linked answer: If the function that you want to use in your html is named `clickFunctionToExport` then you write `window.clickFunctionToExport = clickFunctionToExport;` in the file where that function is defined. And do that for all functions you want to use in your html.